# How do I perform this elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

Lets say I have an index with movie details held by multiple DVD stores. Some of the relevant fields are `'store_id'` , `'genre'` and `'acquired_at'`. For a particular store, I want to retrieve the details of the latest acquired movie for each genre.

I can filter by `'genre'` and `'store_id'` for all possible combinations of those, limit the size to one and sort them in descending order of the `'acquired_at'` key. I was wondering if there is a faster way to do this using aggregations.

Comment: If you can provide more specifics about your use-case and some of what you've tried, that would be helpful for answerers.

I've found the Kibana Dev Console to be very helpful in experimenting with queries, aggregations, and so forth.

Comment: @CraigEddy I have an index that stores details about movie DVDs and which store they belong to for a company owning a chain of DVD stores. I want to know how to find out for each of the store, which was the latest movie they acquired belong to each of the genres. Obviously I can filter by genre and store id for all possible combinations of those, limit the size to one and sort them in descending order of the 'acquired_at' key. I was wondering if there is a faster way to do this using aggregations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have a recent and licensed version of Elastic but there is the ability to find the latest document for a unique key. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/put-transform.html#put-transform. This transform populates the destination index that you specify with the latest documents for each unique key value.